# Print will work across the class, but the action will not

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

When I click my button on the second window, it connects to the top class and successfully prints "yes", when I hit the stop button that binds to self.Hault, the timer stops and it prints.  Is there something silly I am missing when I hit the button on the second window that would make it print, but not perform the action?

```
class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #timer commands
        self.Start_2.clicked.connect(self.start_time)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Time)
        self.Stop.clicked.connect(self.Hault)
        self.window2 = None
    def Hault(self):
        self.timer.stop()

        print ('yes')
class Form(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.main1 = Main()
        self.pop_up_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.main1.Hault)
```

Comment: Are you calling `Main()` in the code outside of what you've shown?  `Form()` is creating its own `Main()` with its own timer, and its button will only stop that timer, not the one in the original `Main()`

Comment: so do I use a signal and a slot to stop it?

Comment: So, are you calling `Main()` elsewhere?  You never actually answered the question...  If so, pass that existing instance to `Form.__init__()`, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: sorry, no I am not calling main anywhere else, I don't really understand what you are really saying by passing the existing form.dunderinit

Comment: Do I do it in the super init line?

Comment: I am right on the edge of finally understanding OOP and I think this is the breakout point!  as soon as you help me with this.

Comment: If you're really only calling `Main()` from that one place, my theory as to the problem can't be right.  Sorry, I have no other ideas.

Comment: Thank you for responding

Comment: I think you are right with my init methods, here is my whole project if you would please look at it http://dpaste.com/2SZFHW2

Comment: Seriously?  There's another call to `Main()` right there, 3rd line from the bottom.  That's the call that initially happens, a button click creates a `Form()`, `Form().__init__()` calls `Main()` again producing an entirely new main window, with its own timer.  The stop button in Form stops that timer, not the one that's actually running in the original Main.  You're already passing a reference to the original Main to `Form()`; save that in `self.main1` rather than calling `Main()` again.